# MWArray to C# array without jumping through hoops

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I'm using MATLAB Builder NE to run some MATLAB functions from C#.

I have a MATLAB 1 row, n column vector of doubles returned from my wrapped dll as an `MWArray` with dimensions 1, n.

What's the easiest way to get a C# `double[]` array from this?  Whatever I do I just seem to get more `MWArrays`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you consider jumping through hoops.  I think you need to cast to one of `MWNumericArray`, `MWLogicalArray`, or `MWCharArray` and use the `ToArray` method as demonstrated [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91689). Say you have a `MWArray` called `aMW`:

```
double[,] ad = (double[,]) ((MWNumericArray) aMW).ToArray(MWArrayComponent.Real);
```

[MWArray class documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dotnetbuilder/MWArrayAPI/HTML/index.html).

As noted by Patrick, use [`ToVector()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dotnetbuilder/MWArrayAPI/html/M_MathWorks_MATLAB_NET_Arrays_MWNumericArray_ToVector.htm) instead of `ToArray()` to get a vector instead of a 2d array.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you add how to get to a 1 dim array double[] ?

Comment: I'm not at all proficient with C#, but I'd imagine if `aMW` is 1D, then you could just do `double[]` instead.  I can't try it.

Comment: In order to get a vector instead of a 2d array, use [`ToVector()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dotnetbuilder/MWArrayAPI/html/M_MathWorks_MATLAB_NET_Arrays_MWNumericArray_ToVector.htm) instead of `ToArray()`. For those who need to return a 2d array as a vector, keep in mind `ToVector()` uses column major order, so you may want to transpose the matrix in the Matlab code before returning, so that you get row major order as a result.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks for the info.  I've added that to the answer for reference, but as I mentioned, I don't really know C#, so I can't comment any further.

Answer (score 0):

If you use compatible version of MWArray than you can try [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MWArray.Extensions.v92/) with MWArray extensions which I created.

Conversion to array of type 'T' is simply done by generic method `ToArray<T>`. In your case `double[] result = aMW.ToArray<double>()`.